# It is possible to run a cardano node through a external drive?

Tags: cardano-node, node

currently i'm running out of storage and just to experiment i'm thinking about to run it through an external drive. Does somenone know if it's possible? And if it is can you give some reference about how to do it?

Thank you forehand, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

You just mean to have all the disk storage the node needs on an external drive? Sure that is possible. How you do it depends on which OS you are running on (eg Windows, Linux, Mac).